# cannot delete from a singly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So I have this `struct`:

```
struct Book {
    char *title;
    char *author;
    int  pages;
    struct Book *next;
}*start=NULL;
```

And i have the following function that i'm using to delete:

```
void delete(int x) {
    struct Book *current;
    for(current = start; current; current = current->next) {
        if(current->pages == x) {
            current = current->next;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if current->next->pages == x then current->next= current->next->next;

Comment: Dont store anything in the head pointer. Just let it be a pointer for address of the first element of the list

Comment: @KishanKumar what if i wanted to delete the last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand the logic behind deleting a node from Linked list. 
Say you have a link-list as x1->x2->x3->x4 and you want to delete x3 from it. So to delete x3, all you have to do is make the `next` pointer of x2 point to to x4. But before u do that your should free the memory allocated to node x3.

Here is a simple code to implement this:

```
void delete(int x) {
struct Book *current;
for(current = start; current; current = current->next) {
if(current->next != NULL){
if(current->next->pages == x) {
    Struct Book * temp = current->next; //save the address of the node to be deleted
    current->next = current->next->next; //remove the node from the linked list
    free(temp->author);
    free(...); //whatever memory you want to release
    free(temp);   //free the memory
    break;
   }   
 }
}
}
```

The above implementation doesn't cover the case when the node to be deleted is the head or root node of the list.

```
void delete(int x) {
if(start == NULL)
    return; 
struct Book *current;
if(start->pages == x)
{
    Struct Book * temp = start; //save the address of the node to be deleted
    start = start->next; //remove the node from the linked list
    free(temp->author);
    free(...); //whatever memory you want to release
    free(temp); 
    return;
}
for(current = start; current; current = current->next)
{
if(current->next != NULL){
if(current->next->pages == x) {
Struct Book * temp = current->next; //save the address of the node to be deleted
current->next = current->next->next; //remove the node from the linked list
free(temp->author);
free(...); //whatever memory you want to release
free(temp);   //free the memory
break;
}   
}
```

}
   }

Comment: yes it will. If LL has only one node which is to be deleted. then the first if condition will be executed hence start will point to null.

Comment: This is not a good solution as there is no indication whether delete() has deleted anything.

Answer (score 1):

you are leaving the list as it is, you need `if(current->pages == x)` then `previous->next = current->next;` and also use `free(current)`

```
void delete(int x) {
struct Book *current;
for(current = start; current; current = current->next) {
  if(current->next != NULL){
    if(current->next->pages == x) {
        current->next = current->next->next;
        break;
     }   
   }
else if(current->pages == x){
 free(current);
 current = NULL;
}

}
```

}

Comment: i think its a singly linked list. And there is also no previous element stored

Comment: What if my list has only one element? or what if i wanted to delete the last element?

Comment: @Kidus Please go through my answer to see how we can check if the node to be deleted is the first node of the LL

Comment: This is not a good solution as there is no indication whether delete() has deleted anything.

Comment: @where_is_tftp I agree. I would make the function return 0 or 1, but I didn't want to stray off too much

Comment: @noob Please take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually remove node from the list. Also, it would be better to have logic split into method that removes list node from list structure and into one that actually deletes it.

```
struct Book* unlink(int x, struct Book *root) {
    struct Book *current = root, *prev = root, *next = NULL;
    while (current) {
        if(current->pages == x) {
            next = current->next;
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            return current;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int delete(int x, struct Book* root) {
    struct Book *found = unlink(x, root);
    if (found != NULL) {
        free(found->title);
        free(found->actor);
        free(found);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}
```